# PHP: Acces value from object with key with $ in front

Tags: php

It`s possible to acces value->$numberDecimal in PHP? This is an API and I can`t replace the $ from front of numberDecimal.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [_id] => 640f3ba1ba5735a9f100cbc4
    [device] => 63d0078ad3a5efee0e4e2f58
    [server] => 63d0041ecd9fdf95257e5937
    [floor] => 1
    [value] => stdClass Object
        (
            [$numberDecimal] => 4185.800000000047
        )

    [index] => stdClass Object
        (
            [$numberDecimal] => 558197.8
        )

    [date] => 1332023
    [updatedDate] => 2023-03-13T15:05:05.926Z
    [__v] => 0
)
```

Thank you!

I tried $response->value->{$numberDecimal}, ${$numberDecimal}, $$numberDecimal but not working